# HTTP requests in an iPhone

Tags: iphone, debugging, http

How can i see HTTP requests sent by my iPhone (inside Safari AND in an app)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) - its super helpful.

Comment: This, and don't forget to first share your mac connection (via AirPort), and make sure your iPhone is connected to the internet through the mac so that Charles can intercept it's traffic

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll test it (on Windows unfortunately)

Comment: Make sure you follow http://blog.mediarain.com/2009/08/iphone-http-connection-debugging/

Comment: Thanks! I'll follow the steps